# Is it possible to write standard conforming random access (or at least forward) Integer Iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

Suppose we have function `f` that that takes integer number and returns a value that increases monotonically. We want find minimal `x` such that `f(x) >= C`. For simplicity let's say that answer is  in range `[l;r)` Obviously we can write our own implementation of binary search but we want to use existing one (`std::patition_point`).

So naive implementation that will (probably) work:

```
// f;
std::vector<int> v(r - l);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), l);
answer = l + partition_point(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int x) {
    return f(x) <= C;
}) - v.begin();
```

The obvious problem is that we have to store all the numbers which takes a lot of memory and also takes time to fill the array

Next logical idea is to wrap integer to iterators in this way:

```
struct IntIterator: std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int> {
    int current;
    IntIterator(int i) : current(i) {}
    int operator*() const { return current; }
    IntIterator& operator++() { ++current; return *this; }
    IntIterator& operator+=(size_t n) { current += (int)n; return *this; }
    IntIterator operator+(size_t n) const { return current+(int)n;  }
    size_t operator-(IntIterator that) const { return size_t(current - that.current); }
    // others operators to conform 
};

answer = partition_point(IntIterator{l}, IntIterator{r}, [&](int x) {
    return f(x) <= C;
});
```

This will work with my compiler (standard library) but is not conforming random access iterator because

- operator* should return `std::iterator_traits<IntIterator>::reference`.
- if we change `std::iterator_traits<IntIterator>::reference` to int (for example by changing template parameters to `std::iterator`) it will not satisfy requirement of forward iterator:

  > if X is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to T; if X is a const iterator, `reference` is a reference to const T,
- if we change return type of `operator*` to `[const ]T&` it will fail to satisfy another requirement of forward iterator

  > If a and b are both dereferenceable, then `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object.

So I don't understand how to make it conforming and question arise whether it's possible.

Comment: What do you mean by saying the naive implementation will probably work? Haven't you tried it?

Comment: I can think of a way to address all of the points here, except that the lifetime of the reference returned by `operator*` is bound to the lifetime of all iterators that compare equal to the dereferenced iterator. I.e. if the iterator being dereferenced is the only iterator for that value, then when the iterator itself goes out of scope, or if its changed (incremented, decremented), then the previously returned reference is no longer valid. Haven't checked whether this would violate the requirements for a random access iterator.

Comment: @VeniVidiVici it means it'll work unless I made typos

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'd like to read your thoughts If you have time sharing them

Comment: Yakk stole my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a const iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`

I think that you shouldn't take this requirement too seriously. Standard library contains a container (`std::vector<bool>`) whose `const_iterator` and `iterator` fail to meet this requirement. I know that there is [**a point of view**](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm) that **"`std::vector<bool>` IS NOT a Container"**, but I am more inclined to see the quoted requirement as too restrictive, than to fully agree with that point of view.

Answer (score 3):

The iterators share a pointer to a cache map.

The cache map maps index to (count, value), where count is the number of iterators at that index.

The iterator remembers if it called `*`.

When `*` is called, the value is populated if missing.  Regardless, count is incremented, then a reference to value is returned.

When the iterator is destroyed, or the iterator moves (`++`), if `*` was called, count is decremented.

If count is decremented to zero, the entry is removed.

This caches the values for all valid iterators of the same index during their collective overlapping lifetime.

Comment: Additionally, the reference count needs to be decremented, et al, if the iterator itself changes (incremented, decremented, etc...)

Comment: Take an iterator, copy it. Increment both.  Compare them: they should come equal. Dereference one. This would create entry in cache. Save address of referenced value. Destroy it. This would decrement counter to 0 and destroy entry. Dereference second iterator. It would create another entry in cache and its address will not compare equal with stored one → requirement violation. You should not actually encounter any problem with it, but, strictly speaking, ForwardIterator concept is too strict for such generator iterators and I do not think that it is possible to fully implement it.

Comment: @revol that is ambiguous, because when you detect the violation, `a` no longer exists.  You have to "time travel" back to when `a` existed, or assume (beyond standard rewuirements) that references are not destroyed/invalidated by iterator destruction/modification.  Is there a requirement in the standard for the reference lifetime beyond the iterator lifetime?  Regardless, even that can be fixed by making it an optional value, doing count inc/dec regardless of `*`, and populating value when `*` is called.

Comment: clever trick, thanks. It's a pity that it'll require allocation per iteration during simple loop (instead of just increment+return in simple case)

Comment: @riad no, you could have 1-5 entries in an array that you linear search beside the map or whatever.  Then the first n living iterstors at once cause no allocation.  Or, use an allocator for the cache that has some auto storage memory.